# Update by query multiple fields using Spring Data Elasticsearch?

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I want to update all the documents that have for exemple the same name. I've seen in the elasticsearch documentation that I can use _update_by_query. So I tried to implement it in my repository like this:

```
@Query("{\"script\": { \"inline\": \"ctx._source.name = ?1\"; \"ctx._source.username = ?2\"; \"ctx._source.avatar = ?3\", \"lang\": \"painless\" }, \"query\": { \"match\": { \"name\" : \"?1\" }}")
List<User> update(String name, String username, String avatar);
```

But I get the following error:

```
nested exception is ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=parsing_exception, reason=[script] query does not support [inline]]]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:157) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 26.06.2020:**

This answer is not correct, I added a correct on.

**Old incorrect answer:**

Seems strange to me, that this error comes from `org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils`.

To update using a script, you can use the `update(UpdateQuery updateQuery, IndexCoordinates index)` of a `ElasticsearchOperations` instance.

To have this in your Repository, you will need to create a repository cusomization like it is [described here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior). In the implementation, autowire a `ElasticsearchOperations` instance. In this custom repository interface, you define the method

```
List<User> update(String name, String username, String avatar);
```

In the implementation, build up a `UpdateQuery` object with the script and the other information and pass this to the `ElasticsearchOperations` instance.

Comment: Can you please share examples on how to use ElasticsearchOperations

Comment: please check my other answer

Answer (score 0):

After checking the code of Spring Data Elasticsearch, I need to withdraw what I wrote in the first answer:

Currently Spring Data Elasticsearch does not support [update by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html). It is only possible to update entities with a know id either in a single operation or in a batch update.

I created [an issue in Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-873) to add support for that.